# Google Chrome does not open PDFs from links

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I am trying to open some auto generated pdf links in Chrome.

Every time when I open such a link, “Failed to load PDF document” message box pops up, but in the same page if I right-click and save the pdf and open that saved file using Chrome, file opens without any issue.

[image]

Also, if I open the same link in Firefox or Internet Explorer, the file opens without any issue.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: I started having this problem today too, but only for *one* PDF that I generated from PowerPoint 2013 that I'm hosting on my Laravel site. Other PDFs that I'd generated in the past still open properly in Chrome. I haven't yet figured out why PowerPoint exported a PDF that isn't working this time.

Comment: I used PowerPoint to generate a fresh PDF, uploaded that to my server, cleared my CloudFlare cache, and then I was able to view the PDF in Chrome Incognito.